# Cast int to double then back to int in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, primitive

quick question.

Would this always be true?

```
int i = ...;
double d = i;
if (i == (int) d) ...
```

Or I need to do rounding to be sure?

```
if (i == Math.round(d)) ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all possible `int` values can round-trip to a `double` safely.

You can verify it with this code:

```
    for (int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE; ; i++) {
        double d = i;
        if (i != (int) d) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("i can't be converted to double and back: " + i);
        }
        if (i == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Note that I'm not using a normal `for` loop, because it would either skip `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or loop indefinitely.

Note that the same is **not** true for `int`/`float` or for `long`/`double`!

Comment: @delnan: Using that condition would skip the test for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for answer. @delnan, checked, it run 20 sec on my computer

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well, with `int/float` and `long/double` it's more capacity problem, not rounding, right?

Comment: @JustYo, its the capacity problem which cause a rounding error in the representation.  Its generally referred to as a rounding error.

Comment: @JustYo , floats creep out at around 2^24. e.g. `int i = 16777217; float f = i; int d = (int)f;` Now `d` is 16777216 !

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a slow computer or don't have time to run the loop to check for yourself, the relevant part of the Java Language Specification is here [§ 5.1.2 Widening Conversions](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-2.0/conversions.doc.html#25214):

> The following 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - **int to long, float, or double**
> - long to float or double
> - float to double
>
> Widening primitive conversions do not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value. **Indeed, conversions widening from an integral type to another integral type and from float to double do not lose any information at all;** the numeric value is **preserved exactly**. [...]

(The following section [§ 5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversions](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-2.0/conversions.doc.html#25363) ensures that the way back, double -> int, doesn't loose any information either.)

Comment: I checked conversion `int<->float`, it brakes on `-2147483647`. After round-trip it becomes `-2147483648`

Comment: Right, `float -> int` however is a narrowing conversion that may loose information.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Joachim's solution.

```
int i=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
do {
    if(i != (int)(double) i) throw new AssertionError(i + " != (int)(double) "+i);
} while(i++ < Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

To find the smallest value which causes an error for a conversion to float.

```
int i = 0;
do {
    if(i != (int)(float) i) throw new AssertionError(i + " != (int)(float) "+i);
} while(i++ < Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

prints

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 16777217 != (int)(float) 16777217
```